# Vertical centering both H1 + H2 lines within responsive banner image

Tags: css

Below is the CSS code I currently use for `<h1>` tags to keep them vertically centered within a responsive banner (corrections welcome). What is the simplest way to add an `<h2>` subtitle within the `<h1>` title, both within the banner, and additionally have the two headings vertically centered with only a breaking space or similar between them?

```
.image {
   position: relative; 
   vertical-align: middle;
}

h1 { 
   font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
   position: absolute; 
   letter-spacing: 3px;
   font-size: 300%;
   text-align: center;
   bottom: 40%;
   width: 100%;
   height: 15%;
   color: white;
}
```

Comment: where's your html? I'm assuming `.image` is not an `img` element? I'd like to see what you have currently. provide a [mcve] please

Comment: I'm assuming you want something like this, but can't tell without seeing all of your code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgMBzm

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a specific height on that banner, you might simply use padding:

```
<header> <!-- with background image -->
  <div id="content">
    <h1></h1>
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
</header>

#content {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3rem 0;
}
```

If the banner has a specific height, then you might use transform:

```
header {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url();
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have successfully added the second line of text. But it does not remain vertically centered on the responsive background image (banner) for _smaller_ screen sizes. IOW the height of the banner reduces proportionally with its width, thereby leaving the text partially below it. How can I set a minimum height below which the banner will not reduce so all the text can be contained within it? I have tried using min-height but it seems to be over-ridden and does not work.

Comment: @PNielsen, it'll be a big help if you post your markup. We're flying blind here without knowing exactly what we're working with.